# Why does my QML background transparency break depending on width setting?

Tags: qt, qml, transparency

I'm running into some strange QML behavior. Basically, I have a `TabBar` header with several tabs running across it. I'd like the `background` element to be mostly the same for each of them, but some of them I want to be able to dynamically change the color of. So I have a component:

```
Component {
    id: standardBackground
    Rectangle {
        opacity: parent.parent.checked ? 0 : (parent.parent.pressed ? 0.8 : 1)
        color: tabColor
    }
}
```

And for each `TabButton`, I'm doing:

```
TabButton {
    text: qsTr("Tab 1")
    background: Loader { sourceComponent: standardBackground }
    height: 60
}
```

This works perfectly, but I'm running into some really strange errors. First off, running it this way gives me the following QML warning:

```
QML TabButton: Binding loop detected for property "implicitWidth"
```

So I figured I could fix this by adding: `width: parent.width` to the `Rectangle` in my component. This *does* silence the warning, but for some reason, it makes it so that the first tab will always be transparent regardless of whether or not it's clicked. This only affects the first tab. I have no clue why this would happen.

However, when I set `width: <anything>`, then this fixes both problems: No warnings and correct transparency. Playing around with different settings for the width causes no noticeable changes, *as long as it's positive*. So I have it set to 1. If I set it to 0, I get the same "implicit width" warnings.

So a couple different questions:

- Why does the transparency of the component break when I set `width: parent.width`?
- Why can I set width to any constant value without it affecting the GUI at all?
- Is there a better way of silencing the warning about implicit width?

Here is my full code (simplified to less tabs):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.0
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings 2.1

import "DataEntry"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 1280
    height: 1024
    visible: true
    title: "Hello World"


    property var tabColor: "#353637"
    property var dummy: InputContext.focus

    Settings {
        id: settings
        property string style: "Universal"
    }

    Component {
        id: standardBackground
        Rectangle {
            opacity: parent.parent.checked ? 0 : (parent.parent.pressed ? 0.8 : 1)
            color: tabColor
            width: 1
        }
    }

    header: TabBar {
        id: bar
        width: parent.width
        height: 60

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Tab 1")
            background: Loader { sourceComponent: standardBackground }
            height: 60
        }

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Tab 2")
            background: Loader {
                sourceComponent: standardBackground

                function getTabColor(error){
                    if (error)
                        return '#cccc00'

                    return window.tabColor
                }

                property var tabColor: getTabColor(hasError)
            }
            height: 60
        }
    }

    StackLayout {
        id: viewStack
        width: parent.width
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: bar.currentIndex

        tab1 {
        }

        tab2 {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are on SO I tend to answer only one question. For you, I choos the question for the binding loop.

The reason for that binding loop is [documented **here**.](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-loader.html#loader-sizing-behavior)

You do not specify a size for the `Loader` so the implicit width of the `Loader` is set to the width specified by the loaded `Item`. Here you set the size to be the same as the `Loader`'s size. Now this would not be a problem, and the result would just be `0`

Now we stir in the `Button` which also has an `implicitSize` set to its styling items. Here the `Loader` is instantiated widht width `0` and then resized to fill the `implicitWidth` of the `Button` which is (without a sized background) depending on the `text` and the `padding`s.

And now we update the round. So, the `implicitWidth` of the `Rectangle` is depending on the `width` of the `Loader` whose `implicitWidth` is depending on the `Rectangle`s width. Further the `Loader`s width is depending on the `Button`s width, which is depending on its `implicitWidth` and which is in turn depending on its `childrenRect.width`...

A binding loop is easily detected even if there are no direct problems, as the system is stabilizing in the first iteration.